# Pandas dataframe: keep only rows depending on actual date and maximum 7 days old

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with articles, here is the first articles:

```
0   La reprise de l’économie française s’étiole et...   Sur le Vieux-Port, à Marseille, le 28 septembr...   2020-10-06
1   Aux Etats-Unis, un rapport parlementaire veut ...   Les icones des services de Google, Amazon, Fac...   2020-10-07
2   Les beaux jours de la médiation en entreprise   Carnet de bureau. Des entreprises appellent de...   2020-10-07
3   Plan de relance : comment « déterminer mainten...   Tribune. Parmi les multiples critiques entendu...   2020-10-07
4   Des lauréats du Nobel qui ne le méritaient pas  Chaque automne, depuis plus d’un siècle, le pe...   2015-10-07
```

I would like to only keep articles that have 7 days maximum from actual date.
Something like this: actual date <= articles <=  7 days old maximum

I have coded this to scrape articles:

```
 %%time

lemonde_title = []
lemonde_content = []
published_date =[]

from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import ArticleException
from datetime import datetime

for art_link in all_urls:
    try:
        art = Article(art_link)
        art.download()
        art.parse()
        
        lemonde_title.append(art.title)
        lemonde_content.append(art.text)
        
        try:
            publish_date = datetime.strptime(str(art.publish_date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%M-%D')
            published_date.append(publish_date)
        except:
            published_date.append('unconverted')
        
    except ArticleException:
        pass
```

I converted the date column like this:

```
# converting the string to datetime format 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%M-%D')
```

And when I try the following code I got an error `TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date`:

```
import datetime
date_before = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
df = df[df['date'] >date_before]
```

Comment: Please share a sample input of data frame with expected output for clarity.

Comment: Hello, I edited my post with an image. Now you can see the dataframe I have

Comment: Having images is not good. Paste your df as code and What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ["t1", "t2", "t3"],
    'date' : ['2020-10-06', '2020-10-05', '2012-10-06']
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

till = pd.to_datetime(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7))
df = df[df['date'] >= till]
```

Output:

```
    text    date
0   t1  2020-10-06
1   t2  2020-10-05
```

Answer (score 0):

use this this works

```
    import datetime
    date_before = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7) 
    df = df[df['date'] >date_before]
```

date before can be edited by you in the way you want to.

Comment: I tried it, I have TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: for that u need to make sure that the data attribute is a datetime object not string

Comment: Thank you, for example  `type(df['date'][0])` gives str type. So I have to convert this column into datetime ?

Comment: yes then as both the columns will be in datatime object so u can compare both.

Comment: I converted the column and now I have `Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date`

Comment: how did my soluy]tion didnt work and the upper one did both are almost same u.

Answer (score 0):

import datetime as dt
df[(dt.datetime.today()-df.date).apply(lambda x: 0<= x.days <7) ]

This should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and I have AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'